# Return the latest date based on the earliest date

Tags: excel, vba

I have two tables one for customer shipment and the other for customer return.

The "customer shipment" table contains dates when a customer buys a reusable product and the "customer return" table contains dates that customer returns.

What i want to be able to do is determine the return date of the customer using dates "customer shipment" table.

For example if a customer took product on lets say 1/1/2021 and 1/12/2021 and in the customer return table i have this customer's return dates of

12/25/2020, 12/31/2020, 1/7/2021 and 1/20/2021.

i want to bring in the "shipment table" the return date of this customer so for the above example,

customer A took product in 1/1/2021 so in the "customer return table", search the latest date next to 1/1/2021 which would be 1/7/2021 and bring all information on that date.

Again

Customer A took product in 1/12/2021 so in the "customer return table", search the latest return date next to 1/12/2021 which would be 1/20/2021 and bring all information on that date.

Thanks in advance for your reply!

Comment: Please include the code you are working with in your question and then explain which part of it is giving your trouble. Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is not a website that you go to with an idea and ask someone else to write all the code for you.

Comment: Well, date plus 6 seems to be the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DMin`:

```
ReturnDate = DMin("[ReturnDate]", "[ShipmentTable]", "[ReturnDate] > #" & Format([Purchase Date], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#")
```